# What is this distribution? (time-delays between two events)

Tags: distributions, qq-plot, distribution-identification

I have a right-skewed distribution that has this qq-plot against a normal with the same mean and standard deviation:

[image: QQ-Plot]

The data are time-delays between two events. Also, this is the histogram of the data:
[image]

and this is the QQ-plot of log(data + 1), vs. normal of the same mean and standard deviation as the log(data+1) values:

[image]

I have tried fitting Weibull, lognormal, and Pareto, without success. Any thoughts on what would be the right candidate?

Comment: How did you try fitting these distributions? You might also post a histogram, some more details about what kind of data this is (that might affect the distributions/methods proposed), and what the purpose of your analysis is. The more information the more people here can do to help. With that said, if you don't **know** that is is a standard distribution then it would be a breeze to fit a mixture of Normals to it.

Comment: It's very difficult to assess which distribution something *is*, but easy to tell what it *isn't* (it isn't normal!).  At best you might hope to identify some distribution that might give a reasonable  description. If the values are all $>0$, what does a QQ plot of the logs look like?

Comment: @Matthew, you lost me. I can't see how one could fit a finite mixture of normals to something like this.

Comment: @Mathew, the data represent time delays between two events. I am interested in comparing the behavior of these delays under various conditions.

Comment: @Glen_b, I added the QQ-plot of log(data+1) to the question.

Comment: @user765195 It looks discrete, not continuous. What are the values measuring?  (I know, time delays, but why are the values discrete?) It's right skew, with a lot of zeroes, and looks lighter in the right-tail than lognormal.

Comment: Actually, it might be well enough approximated by either a gamma, or a mixture of two gammas, which are then truncated (presumably to integers, though it's hard to tell exactly).

Comment: @Glen_b, the delays are rounded to the nearest hour. They were originally in seconds.

Comment: @Glen_b, thanks for the suggestion. I'll try Gammas and mixture of Gammas.

Comment: The rounding can have odd effects, which you may need to worry about.

Comment: Assuming you're using R .... Here's an example of the sort of shape you might get: `x=c(rgamma(9950,.15,1/9000),rgamma(50,.15,1/9000));
x1=round(x+.4);qqnorm(log(1+x1))`  ... it's not perfect, but not bad for trying to pick by eye. Mixtures of other lighter-than-lognormal choices may work better. Note that I have a mixture of (slightly) shifted gamma rvs

Comment: @Glen_b. This is an awesome looking QQ-plot. How did you get the parameters?

Comment: I just took a guess at the shape parameter - it seemed from your plot it should be less than 1, and I tried 0.1, 0.2 and 0.5, any of which looked roughly right, but the shape wasn't quite there - I couldn't get both ends right at the same time. I tried a couple of mixtures and then added a shift to get something vaguely like the right shape. Essentially trial and error (with a bit of knowledge at the start) to get a rough approximation. No doubt you could do better.

Comment: @Glen_b. Many thanks! I wish I could upvote your comment 10 times rather than once.

Comment: I'll write up a brief description of what I did, and point out the remaining deficiencies.

Comment: Actually, playing around a bit, a mixture of two lognormals also looks like a reasonable model.

Comment: @user765195 I said a mixture of normals without looking at plot. Like Glen_b said a mixture of lognormals or gammas would make more sense. However, I don't think you'd be too far off in RMSE/likelihood measure/whatever if you did an infinite mixture of truncated normals through a finite approximation to the dirichlet process. Of course it would be unnecessary with the more appropriate kernels of lognormal and gamma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your second Q-Q plot, it gives us some clues  - if it were lognormal, the upper right part would look straight.

So that suggests that perhaps it's something lighter-tailed than lognormal, at least for the larger values.

A right-skew distribution that's lighter-tailed than lognormal is the gamma. It seems pretty skew - substantially more skew than an exponential for example, so it suggests a shape parameter smaller than 1.

Here's an example:

```
x=c(rgamma(1000,.1,1/9000))
x1=round(x);qqnorm(log(1+x1))
```

[image]

However, it's difficult to get the shape of the Q-Q plot quite right; one possibility is that a mixture of two gammas might do better.

Another thing to consider is shifted gamma distributions - adding something like 0.4 before rounding does seem to improve the shape at the low end.

Experiments with mixtures does suggest that a finite mixture with a few components might do quite well, so it's probably worth trying a 2 or 3 component mixture of gammas or shifted gammas (or indeed similar less-skew-than-lognormal distributions) and using a decent fitting algorithm, rather than the bit of trial and error I used to get this far.